# Call componentWillReceiveProps in componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `react`, i want to call a `function` in another `function` for example i need to call `componentWillReceiveProps` in `componentWillMount` ? How to do that?

```
import React from 'react'
class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    enter code here
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps)
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h>hiiiiii</h1>
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: Why do **you** need to call it? The [component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) will call it for you.

Comment: because redux do not call component will receive props if the previous data is same

Comment: If the props are not changing, then why do you need to call it?  The whole point of the lifecycle functions is to give you hooks into certain parts of the rendering process.  If they are not being called there is a good reason and trying to call them seems like the wrong approach.  Perhaps you should try to describe what you are trying to achieve, not what you are trying to do, so we can help you find a better way.

Comment: suppose i call an api for edit funcitonality and my input fields are filled up by that .... and when i move to different routes and come again to that edit page than my data is same and component will receive props did not called and my input fields are remains blank...

Comment: What are you doing in `componentWillReceiveProps` that needs to happen for this to just work?  Just rerendering the component should not leave the inputs blank, especially if the props have not changed.  You will need to show more of the actual code inside `componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and `render` for me to help more.  You can just do as Amin Jafari's answer suggests, but I'm worried there are some structural mistakes that should be addressed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you'd better do is to create a method in which you want the operation to execute and call that method inside the componentWillReceiveProps and componentWillMount.

```
import React from 'react'
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._myMethod=this._myMethod.bind(this);

    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this._myMethod(this.props);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this._myMethod(nextProps);
    }
    _myMethod(props){
        console.log(props);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h>hiiiiii</h1>
            </div>
        )}
}
```